How to read data from Apache HBase using Apache Spark in Jupyter Notebook?
I am using docker to run HBase, Jupyter, Zookeeper.
I have created a simple table in Apache HBase as shown below. (docker-compose exec hbase hbase shell)
create 'student', 'info'
put 'student', '1', 'info:name', 'John'
put 'student', '1', 'info:age', '20'
put 'student', '1', 'info:gender', 'Male'
put 'student', '1', 'info:grade', 'A'
put 'student', '2', 'info:name', 'Alice'
put 'student', '2', 'info:age', '22'
put 'student', '2', 'info:gender', 'Female'
put 'student', '2', 'info:grade', 'B'
put 'student', '3', 'info:name', 'Bob'
put 'student', '3', 'info:age', '21'
put 'student', '3', 'info:gender', 'Male'
put 'student', '3', 'info:grade', 'C'
Now I want to read this data in Apache Spark in Jupyter Notebook. My Spark version is 3.1.2 and my Scala version is 2.12.10
My code is as below
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Spark init
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local") \
    .appName('jupyter-pyspark') \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "it.agilelab:wasp-plugin-hbase-spark_2.12:2.33.0-emr212") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Load data into a DataFrame
student_df = spark.read \
    .format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark") \
    .option("hbase.table", "student") \
    .option("hbase.columns.mapping", "rowkey,info:name,info:age,info:gender,info:grade") \
    .option("hbase.use.hbasecontext", False) \
    .load()

# Show the DataFrame
student_df.show()


This is the error i get
IllegalArgumentException: Invalid value for hbase.columns.mapping 'rowkey,info:name,info:age,info:gender,info:grade'
as shown in the print screen

I am just expecting to read the data from HBase to Spark.
